# Initializer syntax for list properties

Tags: c#

I witnessed something strange when initializing a class with a List as a property. When doing this

```
var stuff = new Stuff(){list = {1, 2, 3} };
```

It compiles, and crashes saying that list is null. So, adding this to Stuff's constructor:

```
public Stuff(){
    list = new List<int>();
}
```

List is now initialized to contain `{1, 2, 3}` which seems to make some sense. But then, changing the constructor to

```
public Stuff(){
    list = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3};
}
```

And initializing like so

```
var stuff = new Stuff(){list = {4, 5, 6} };
```

list is initialized to contain `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` leaving me rather confused.

It seems like this either shouldn't compile, or shouldn't behave this way. What exactly is going on here?

Comment: [code](http://ideone.com/9gtwOC) here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like this either shouldn't compile, or shouldn't behave this way. What exactly is going on here?

Collection initializers work by calling the `.Add` method on each item passed into the initializer.  This *adds* them to the items you pre-populate within your constructor.

This is explained in [the documentation for Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx):

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements IEnumerable. The element initializers can be a simple value, an expression or an object initializer. By using a collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple calls to the Add method of the class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.

This means the compiler turns your second call into something similar to:

```
var temp = new Stuff();
temp.list.Add(4);
temp.list.Add(5);
temp.list.Add(6);
Stuff stuff = temp;
```

As you can see, the `stuff` variable will call the constructor normally (which adds `1`, `2`, and `3`), then add the other items, resulting in what you see.

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing `list` using a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx). This way this works is given in the documentation:

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element
>   initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements
>   `IEnumerable`. The element initializers can be a simple value, an
>   expression or an object initializer. By using a collection initializer
>   you do not have to specify multiple calls to the `Add` method of the
>   class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.

In other words, this:

```
var stuff = new Stuff(){list = {1, 2, 3} };
```

is a shorthand way of writing this:

```
var temp = new Stuff();
temp.list.Add(1);
temp.list.Add(2);
temp.list.Add(3);
stuff = temp;
```

It's easy to see how this would cause a `NullReferenceException` if `list` is `null` and how it appends to the existing items in the list, if any.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Thanks for the catch -- I fixed that and it now is the same as yours :*)